# Why does Hibernate JPA throw LazyInitialization exception when using getReference()?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate 5.2.11 as a JPA provider. I have an annotated class (PurchaseOrder) with another annotated class (Customer) as a field with a many-to-one relationship. BUT because the legacy code had the Customer and PO tables in different databases, I have a call to EntityManager's getReference() in PurchaseOrder to return the Customer instance. I access these through a home-brewed class that uses Hibernate (details follow).
This is resulting in the following exception:

org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

I've been reading through the Hibernate, JPA and Java EE docs, but haven't been able to puzzle out what I'm doing wrong. I know that Hibernate is using a Session behind the scenes to enable JPA capabilities, but when I access .getCustomer(), I'm creating a new EntityManager, so it should have the session it needs.

It's plain that I'm missing a crucial bit of understanding, but I have no idea what it is. Can anyone enlighten me?

Here is the significant part of Purchase Order, which consists of Strings, Integers, Booleans and LocalDates (ie: they're all @Basic fields), and Customer as the only contained class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PurchaseOrder")
public class PurchaseOrder extends BaseEntity { // BaseEntity is a @mappedSuperclass containing the primary key info only.
...
    private Integer customerID;
    private Customer customer;
...
    @Column(name = "customerID")
    public Integer getCustomerID() {
        return customerID;
    }

    public void setCustomerID(Integer customerID) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
    }

    @Transient
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        LOG.info("Getting customer #{}", customerID);
        if (customerID != 0 && (customer == null || !customerID.equals(customer.getId()))) {
            customer = VdtsSysDB.getDB().get(Customer.class, customerID);
        }
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.customerID = customer.getId();
    }
...
```

And this is Customer, which consists only of @Basic fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Customers")
public class Customer extends BaseEntity{
    private String custNo;
    private String businessName;
    private String contact;
...
    @Column(name = "custNo")
    public String getCustNo() {
        return custNo;
    }

    public void setCustNo(String custNo) {
        this.custNo = custNo;
    }

    @Column(name = "Name")
    public String getBusinessName() {
        return businessName;
    }

    public void setBusinessName(String businessName) {
        this.businessName = businessName;
    }

    @Column(name = "Contact")
    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(String contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
    ...
```

This is my Hibernate utility class:

```
public class VdtsSysDB {
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private static VdtsSysDB vdtsSysDB;

    public static VdtsSysDB getDB() {
        if (vdtsSysDB == null) {
            vdtsSysDB = new VdtsSysDB();
        }
        return vdtsSysDB;
    }

    private VdtsSysDB() {
        if (entityManagerFactory == null)
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("VDTS_SYSDB");
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        try {
            entityManager.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Exception logging.
        }
    }
...
    /**
     * Issues an HQL Query and returns the results as a list.
     *
     * @param queryString - An HQL query.
     * @return A list of items representing the returned dataset.
     */
    public <T extends BaseEntity> List<T> query(String queryString) {
        List<T> results = null;
        LOG.info("Query: {}", queryString);
        EntityManager entityManager = null;
        try {
            entityManager = getEntityManager();
            results = entityManager.createQuery(queryString).getResultList();
            entityManager.close();
            LOG.info("Returned {} results.", results.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (entityManager != null && entityManager.isOpen()) entityManager.close();
            LOG.error("Unable to complete query {}.", queryString, e);
        }
        return results;
    }

    /**
     * Get an object from the database by specifying its class and its ID.
     * @param aClass the class type to be returned.
     * @param id the primary key to the item to be returned.
     * @param <T> the class type to be returned.
     * @return A single instance of the specified item of this class.
     */
    public <T extends BaseEntity> T get(Class aClass, Integer id) {
        LOG.info("Get #: {}, {}", id, aClass.getName());
        T result = null;
        EntityManager entityManager = null;
        try {
            entityManager = getEntityManager();
            Object object = entityManager.getReference(aClass, id);
            result = (T) object;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Could not get {}", id, e);
        } finally {
            closeEntityManager(entityManager);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The code which throws the exception is part of a JavaFX 8 application controller. initialize() is called on class load, while refreshPane() is called whenever the attached GUI is displayed. The exception is thrown on the call to Customer.getBusinessName().

```
@FXML
private TableView<PurchaseOrder> poTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<PurchaseOrder, String> poNoCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<PurchaseOrder, String> customerNameCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<PurchaseOrder, LocalDate> orderDateCol;

@Override
protected void initialize() {
    super.initialize();
    poTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (newValue != null) selectItem();
            });
    poNoCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("purchaseOrderNo"));
    customerNameCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
        PurchaseOrder po = param.getValue();
        Customer customer = po.getCustomer();
        String name = customer.getBusinessName(); /****** This is the line that throws the exception ******/
        StringProperty observableString = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        return observableString;
            });
    orderDateCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("orderDate"));    
...
}

@Override
protected void refreshPane() {
    List<Customer> oList = VdtsSysDB.getDB().query("from Customer");
    customerCombo.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(oList));
    changeTable();
    clearWidgets();
    enableWidgets(false);
}

private void changeTable() {
    poTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    List<PurchaseOrder> oList = VdtsSysDB.getDB()
            .query("from PurchaseOrder where closed = " + (openRadio.isSelected() ? "0" : "1"));
    poTable.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(oList));
}
...
```

The full stack trace of the exception:

```
30-09-17 19:42:05.137 ERROR java.lang.Throwable - Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
30-09-17 19:42:05.137 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:146)
30-09-17 19:42:05.138 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:259)
30-09-17 19:42:05.139 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:73)
30-09-17 19:42:05.139 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at ca.vdts.buchanan.model.Customer_$$_jvst799_9.getBusinessName(Customer_$$_jvst799_9.java)
30-09-17 19:42:05.139 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at ca.vdts.buchanan.endtally.controllers.POController.lambda$initialize$1(POController.java:103)
30-09-17 19:42:05.140 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
30-09-17 19:42:05.140 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:563)
30-09-17 19:42:05.140 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:644)
30-09-17 19:42:05.141 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:468)
30-09-17 19:42:05.141 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
30-09-17 19:42:05.141 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:533)
30-09-17 19:42:05.141 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.init(TableRowSkinBase.java:147)
30-09-17 19:42:05.142 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:64)
30-09-17 19:42:05.142 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:212)
30-09-17 19:42:05.142 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:872)
30-09-17 19:42:05.142 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9058)
30-09-17 19:42:05.143 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9155)
30-09-17 19:42:05.143 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1964)
30-09-17 19:42:05.143 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1797)
30-09-17 19:42:05.143 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1879)
30-09-17 19:42:05.144 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2528)
30-09-17 19:42:05.144 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1189)
30-09-17 19:42:05.144 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
30-09-17 19:42:05.144 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
30-09-17 19:42:05.145 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
30-09-17 19:42:05.145 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
30-09-17 19:42:05.145 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
30-09-17 19:42:05.145 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
30-09-17 19:42:05.146 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
30-09-17 19:42:05.146 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
30-09-17 19:42:05.146 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
30-09-17 19:42:05.147 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
30-09-17 19:42:05.147 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
30-09-17 19:42:05.147 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
30-09-17 19:42:05.147 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
30-09-17 19:42:05.148 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
30-09-17 19:42:05.148 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
30-09-17 19:42:05.148 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
30-09-17 19:42:05.148 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
30-09-17 19:42:05.149 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
30-09-17 19:42:05.149 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
30-09-17 19:42:05.150 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
30-09-17 19:42:05.150 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
30-09-17 19:42:05.150 ERROR java.lang.Throwable -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oy. Why is it you only ever figure out the answer AFTER you've posted the question?

This exception is being thrown because of my use of EntityManager.getReference().

From the Java EE JPA Javadocs:

> Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched. If the requested
>   instance does not exist in the database, the EntityNotFoundException
>   is thrown when the instance state is first accessed. (The persistence
>   provider runtime is permitted to throw the EntityNotFoundException
>   when getReference is called.) The application should not expect that
>   the instance state will be available upon detachment, unless it was
>   accessed by the application while the entity manager was open.

I was trying to access the fields of Customer, which getReference fetched lazily. Those fields had not been initialized prior to my closing the EntityManager, so any attempt to reference them was bound to throw a LazyInitialization exception.

The solution here is obvious: don't use getReference. Use EntityManager.find() instead.